# Adding two random variables (probability distributions)

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

Let's consider two balanced dice. I am modelling each of them using

```
d1 = ProbabilityDistribution[1/6, {x, 1, 6, 1}]
d2 = ProbabilityDistribution[1/6, {x, 1, 6, 1}]
```

Call $x$ the result of the first dice and $y$ the result of the second dice after they are thrown, let $z=2x+y$. How can I make a probability distribution corresponding to $z$ using $d_1$ and $d_2$ ? I tried adding them

```
d3=2*d1+d2
```

but this didn't work.

Comment: I think you want `TransformedDistribution`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Eric Brown suggested you should use [TransformedDistribution[]](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html). Also I'd suggest using built in distributions if possible, here I mean [DiscreteUniformDistribution[]](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscreteUniformDistribution.html).

```
tf = TransformedDistribution[
  A + B, {A \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}], 
   B \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}]}]
PDF[tf, x]
DiscretePlot[PDF[tf, x], {x, 2, 12}]
```

[image]

Comment: Just as a tiny comment:  it would be better to first evaluate:  `ee = PDF[tf, x]`, and then `DiscretePlot[ee {x, 2, 12}]` . By contrast, `DiscretePlot[PDF[tf, x], {x, 2, 12}]` might take about 100 times longer to plot, because it tells Mma to calculate `PDF[t,x]` at each value of x (rather than just solving it once).